# Text having stroke/outline on Android Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, fonts, accessibility

I have an issue in Moto G 2nd Gen running Lollipop. It shown a stroke/outline on the text for the entire display. I thought it may or may not be an OS issue.

I tried searching this option in Settings to change the style, but I didn't find anything about it.

Is it possible to turn this off?

Here with I've attached the screenshot, what the difficulties I faced.

[image: Home Screen Tray] [image: Home Screen- Red Circle are drawn to Identify My Issues]

<sub>Screenshots - (Click to enlarge image)</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've (accidentally) turned on "high contrast text" accessibility option, an experimental feature on Lollipop. From [Google official support](https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/6151855),

> **High contrast text**
>
> This information applies only to devices running Android 5.0 and higher.
>
> High contrast makes text easier to read on your device. This feature fixes the text color as either black or white, depending on the original text color.
>
> To enable or disable high contrast text, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Go to **Settings > Accessibility**.
> 2. Select **High contrast text**.
>
> High-contrast text is currently an experimental feature, so it might not work correctly everywhere on your device.

Comment: Thank You for your support Mr.Andrew, I Follow the step and resolve it. My Device Become Clear Visible Font Appearence. Thanks a lot.